# access "Application" in custom module

Tags: java, android, react-native

I want to create custom module in android with react native.
I have files

- /java/com/my_app/MainApplication.java
- /java/com/my_app/MyCustomModule.java

In MyCustomModule.java

```
import SomeExternalLibrary;

public class MyCustomModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

   @ReactMethod
   public void build(String key){
      new SomeExternalLibrary.build(
           this, //here is i get error 
           key
          )
   }
}
```

If i run this get error

> incompatible types: MyCustomModule cannot be converted to Application

If i put it in `onCreate` method in `MainApplication.java` it worked.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(){
     super.onCreate();
     new SomeExternalLibrary.build(this, "key")
  }
}
```

Is there any way to access Application in MyCustomModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
  new SomeExternalLibrary.build(
       getCurrentActivity().getApplication(),
       key
  )
```